# Linear Interpolation starting from zero

Tags: r

I have a daily time series data set that I am attempting to perform an hourly linear interpolation on.  My code is performing a linear interpolation between points but I need to start from 0 after the last point per ID and start of the new day.

Below is my output after adding missing hours to the daily raw data

[image]

Below is my output after performing the following code, but I am not sure how to start from 0:

```
dfYPO0_20171 <- dfYPO0_2017 
%>% mutate(TIMESTAMP = as.POSIXct(as.character(TIMESTAMP))) 
%>% group_by(ID) 
%>% do(left_join(data.frame(ID= .$ID[1], TIMESTAMP = seq(min(.$TIMESTAMP), max(.$TIMESTAMP), by = "hour")), ., by=c("ID", "TIMESTAMP"))) 
%>% mutate(CALC_HOURLY_PROD= na.approx(.$"Total Prod Yest"))
```

[image]

Below is what I would like my output to look like:

[image]

Thanks for any help in advance!

Comment: Copy the column, fill in the zero's first and then run `na.approx`?

Comment: Please do not provide your data with an image. No one wants to type it all in again. Instead, please use `dput` to make a printable form of your data and paste it into your question.

Comment: Sorry about that, I will ensure it won't happen in the future.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an approach using `tidyverse` packages. First, we'll create groups based on the runs of missing values, then we'll use `approx` to interpolate.

```
library(tidyverse)

# Fake data
dat = data.frame(time=seq(as.Date("2015-01-01"), as.Date("2015-01-31"), "1 day"),
                 prod=c(10.4, rep(NA,19), 25.8, rep(NA,9), 14.2))

dat = dat %>% 
  # Create groups based on runs of NA followed by a value
  mutate(group = rev(cumsum(!is.na(rev(prod))))) %>% 
  # Operate on the groups we just created
  group_by(group) %>% 
  # First, add a zero at the beginning of each group, then run the approx function
  #  to interpolate values for all groups of length greater than 1 
  mutate(prod = replace(prod, row_number()==1 & n()>1, 0),
         prod = if(n()>1) approx(time, prod, xout=time)$y else prod) %>%
  ungroup %>% select(-group)
```

> ```
>          time      prod
> 1  2015-01-01 10.400000
> 2  2015-01-02  0.000000
> 3  2015-01-03  1.357895
> ...
> 19 2015-01-19 23.084211
> 20 2015-01-20 24.442105
> 21 2015-01-21 25.800000
> 22 2015-01-22  0.000000
> 23 2015-01-23  1.577778
> 24 2015-01-24  3.155556
> ...
> 29 2015-01-29 11.044444
> 30 2015-01-30 12.622222
> 31 2015-01-31 14.200000
> ```

Comment: Worked perfectly, thanks for showing me a new package too!